# Toolbar image animation collapse style

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a `Toolbar` that when i get to the `Activity` has an image expanded and the `Toolbar` title at the bottom of the image, and when i scroll the content below the `Toolbar`, the image disappears and the toolbar title moves to the top position.

The easiest way i can explain it is in the attached image:
        [image: Scroll up example]

The code i currently have is below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_list_item"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ui.activities.ItemBuyNowActivity">


  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/appbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/orange_6"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_buy_now_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/buy_now_tool_bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:id="@+id/list_item_cart_fab"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
  android:src="@drawable/cart_empty_dark"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: The long lost question is, that i would like my toolbar to appear below the image, and when scrolled up it will stop at the top and the image would have disappeared.

Currently, the Title is at the bottom of the image but overlaying the image, and when scrolled to the top the title is at the top and the image had disappeared as its meant to.

The problem is that i need the toolbar to be below the image when the toolbar is fully expanded!

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You will get more information just run demo and see code as well https://github.com/bsuhas/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop

Comment: @PPartisan - That's a really good question :)

Comment: @PPartisan hahaha! sorry about that guys!!! Will amend

Comment: @SuhasB mine is currently doing what its shows in this gif https://goo.gl/HpN67u i need the tool bar title to start below the image then move to the position when collapsed as it is in the gif

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this already so easy.

Replace your current code with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

           <!-- This is the image you want to add -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

           <!-- Toolbar to just hold the action icons -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

           <!-- Nested scroll to make the content under the bar scrolls and move up and down the collapsing toolbar -->

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

           <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: It could be better if you explained it a bit, not just code.

Comment: No need to explain, it's just explain it self, I added some comments in the code.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about the question :) but,: `when i get to the Activity has an image` he has it but in the codes, it wasn't.

Comment: He just try to make the collapsing toolbar and don't have any images, I think he just explain what he trying to do and want help! :3

Comment: Let's see after the edit, anyways, don't use that: `app:layout_behavior` in your `CoordinatorLayout `.

Comment: ok i did this, but no change really in the sense that the Toolbar Title is still overlaying the Toolbar Image. I need the title below the tool bar image when the toolbar is fully expanded, but you did answer another issue i had which wasnt mentioned in this question regarding the Scrolling, i was trying to find a way to scroll with the content and not only the toolbar (NestedScrollView)

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that when i do scroll to the bottom, the Toolbar action icons dissapear? anyway to prevent this, using the code you gave me?